# Can't set up dual-monitor in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: multiple-monitors

First, I encountered "Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS [pc name] tty1" (Doesn't work <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)

So I take action below

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-greeter sudo apt-get install --purge unity-greeter
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
startx
```

Then problem is solved (i can see XWindow),

But doesn't work dual-monitor and aero

connected two monitors to desktop but each monitor is showing same screen(like mirroring)

Thanks in advane!

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to a newer release. Mine wasn't working either but in 15.04 it worked out of the box.